# How to retrieve the element that was dropped upon?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I have the following XAML code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding UserBase}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding User}" 
         SelectionMode="Single" 
         AllowDrop="True"
         myOwnDragDrop:DragDropSource="{Binding}"
         myOwnDragDrop:DragDropTarget="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" AllowDrop="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ListBox x:Name="ListBox2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding UserBase}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding User}" 
         SelectionMode="Single"
         myOwnDragDrop:Source="{Binding}"
         myOwnDragDrop:Target="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" AllowDrop="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So this actually works in my MVVM implementation (at least the dragging and dropping part). The problem is that in the interface of both of the dependent properties only gives me:

```
public void Drop(object data)
```

Where data is actually the entire view object in which ListBox1 resides. In theory there is no problem, but I was wondering how do I get the correct user that was dropped upon without making any changes to the interface or dependent property implementation?

Note the dependent property seems to be handling the event `private static void Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)`, but I can't access the `e`.

In case this is totally impossible, is it possible to retrieve the user that was dropped upon from the DragEventArgs?

Thank you for everything!

Answer (score -1):

First of all: Have you looked at [GongSolutions WPF DragDrop](http://punker76.github.io/gong-wpf-dragdrop/) library?

It's free, and available on NuGet, and makes implementing drag/drop in WPF a lot easier, but with still retaining complete control over the process.

In particular, the Drop() method exposes an IDropInfo object, which gives you access to all sorts of information about the drag/drop process (including the source and target UIElements).

I spent quite a bit of time trying to implement drag and drop from scratch a while ago, but found this library far easier to implement, and it allowed me to add all my drag/drop functionality to my ViewModel rather than my codebehind.

There's some good get-you-started documentation on the GitHub pages.

Secondly, with regards to how do you obtain the user the drag was dropped onto (without using the above library):

When I implemented drag/drop between listboxes, I found I needed to enable and handle AllowDrop on **each ListItem**. You might want to try creating a custom ItemPanelTemplate for your listbox, and enabling AllowDrop on the panel. That way, the 'object data' you will receive should the the ListItemPanel, from which you can access the DataContext to obtain the User.

Comment: I am not sure whether I have explained myself correctly or I do not understand your second explanation. Suppose I drag user1 onto user2, I would like to get a pointer towards user2. In your case I would get user1 or am I wrong? I am interested in the object that gets squished when I drop my user1 onto it.

Comment: @Snowflake can you give me some more information about your implementation? Where is this Drop() method? How is it called? And what are the **myOwnDragDrop:... ** attached properties?